# How do I declare a variable in a specific scope in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine

I'm trying to write a jasmine test in coffeescript that uses a beforeEach block. This runs into a problem with coffeescript's variable scoping. Here's what I'd like to write:

```
describe 'PhoneDetailCtrl', () ->
  beforeEach () ->
    scope = angular.scope()
    $browser = scope.$service('$browser')

  it 'should fetch phone detail', () ->
    scope.params = {phoneId:'xyz'}
    $browser.xhr.expectGET('phones/xyz.json').respond({name:'phone xyz'})
    ctrl = scope.$new(PhoneDetailCtrl)

    expect(ctrl.phone).toEqualData({})
    $browser.xhr.flush()

    expect(ctrl.phone).toEqualData({name:'phone xyz'})
```

This doesn't work, though, because the `scope` and `$browser` will get declared with `var` in the innermost scope. That is, once in the `beforeEach` and then again in the `it` block. I can force the variables to be declared in the right scope by initializing them, but this seems very strange:

```
describe 'PhoneDetailCtrl', () ->
  $browser = {}
  scope = {}
  beforeEach () ->
    scope = angular.scope()
    $browser = scope.$service('$browser')

  it 'should fetch phone detail', () ->
    scope.params = {phoneId:'xyz'}
    ...
```

This works, but the javascript it compiles to is actually

```
describe('PhoneListCtrl', function() {
  var $browser, ctrl, scope;
  $browser = {};
  ctrl = {};
  scope = {};
```

where all I need is the line `var $browser, ctrl, scope;`. Can I write this more concisely in coffeescript?

Comment: I think it's fine to keep the initializer at the top like that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are doing it the right way.

This is described in the [CoffeeScript documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope).  I wouldn't worry about the JS that it creates.  Yes, it is a bit messy if you were to write it yourself, but this is one of the things that you have to live with when you use a re-writer like CoffeeScript.

You do, however, have a couple of options which are pretty nice.

You can put the variables in the current context if you wish (which happens to be your jasmine.Spec object for the curious, so it is a relatively safe and appropriate place to be putting variables... just don't overwrite [existing vars in the context](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/Spec.js).):

```
describe 'PhoneDetailCtrl', () ->
  beforeEach () ->
    @scope = angular.scope()
    @$browser = @scope.$service('$browser')

it 'should fetch phone detail', () ->
  @scope.params = {phoneId:'xyz'}
  #... etc
```

You can also setup your own variable in which to store things

```
describe 'PhoneDetailCtrl', () ->
  setup = {}

  beforeEach () ->
    setup.scope = angular.scope()
    setup.$browser = setup.scope.$service('$browser')

  it 'should fetch phone detail', () ->
    setup.scope.params = {phoneId:'xyz'}
    #... etc
```

Answer (score 10):

Your test could be written like the following:

```
describe "MyGame", ->
    mygame = null
    beforeEach inject (_MyGame_) ->
        mygame = _MyGame_

    it "should have two players", ->
        expect(mygame.opponents.length).toEqual 2
```

Much cleaner syntax - without the need to make things global.

Comment: You can also use `a = b = c = d = null` for spare lines. The variables won't affect each other (as opposed to if you'd assign them to `{}`)

Comment: You link's dead. I'm not sure if/where it is now, or I'd suggest an edit.